# AccessTokenProviderChain and OAuth2RestOperations

Tags: spring-security-oauth2

The [Spring OAuth2 Developers Guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html) show the following under Persisting Tokens in a Client:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {
    OAuth2RestTemplate template = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(accessTokenRequest));
    AccessTokenProviderChain provider = new AccessTokenProviderChain(Arrays.asList(new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider()));
    provider.setClientTokenServices(clientTokenServices());
    return template;
}
```

However, I don't understand how the provider is part actually being used.  Is this missing:

```
template.setAccessTokenProvider(provider);
```

Or is something else going on?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right, `accessTokenProvider` should be set in the template.

See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-oauth2-authentication-with-reddit